# How does the norm of a cross product in 3-space give squared units?

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product

It has been given in my textbook that the area of a parallelogram whose distinct sides are formed by the vectors ***v*** and ***u*** is  $\|v\times u\| $. But why would the norm of the cross product $(x,y,z)$ be a squared unit? I'm thinking that taking the norm maps a vector to a length, which is not a squared unit.

Comment: Mathematically the "unit" is not part of it. It's just a number (scalar).

Comment: @Warren The cross product is still a "product". If you multiply two vectors with a certain unit of length, then the unit of the cross product is $[\text{length}]^2$.

Comment: @Warren Still, it is a bit strange how even though $u,v$ and $v\times u$ are all vectors, their units are different. One deeper explanation to be given here is that the notion of $v \times u$ as a vector is actually a convenient fiction. In a sense, what $v \times u$ "really is" is the [bivector $v \wedge u$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#External_product).